# Sum column returns inaccurate result

Tags: php, sql, mysqli

I'm working on a bit of code to sum the number of seconds in a 'duration' column of a mysql table. The code I'm currently using seems to be summing all of the rows of the column, EXCEPT the first row.

So for example, if the table contains 3 rows as such as:

1. 10
2. 15
3. 20

The sum of that column SHOULD be 45, but instead the code I'm using will return 35 and completely skip over the first row in the table.

Here is my current code:

```
// GET THE DATA FROM THE 'DURATION' COLUMN
$sql = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(duration) AS total FROM timesheet WHERE username='$qname' AND payperiod='$payperiod'");

// LOOP AND ADD ALL THE DATA IN THE DURATION COLUMN
while ($result = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql))
{ 
   $duration = $result['total'];
}
```

What am I missing? The code works as far as it runs and produces a sum assigned to the variable $duration, however the sum amount is incorrect and always seems to have skipped the first row of the table in the column to be summed.

In the following screen shot, the column being summed is the 'DURATION' column in the first table. The sum is then converted to a decimal representation of hours and displayed in the 'TOTAL HOURS' column of the second table. No matter what values are fed into the table, the end result, the TOTAL HOURS is always missing the data from the first row.

[image: Screenshot of output]

When I run the same queries on the mysql database itself, bypassing the PHP, I get the same results. Below are screenshots of the queries run on the database.

[These are the rows that are being queried](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A2kfF.png)

[This is the sum result returned by the database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BeQqn.png)

You can see from the screenshots that there are 3 records found, the first record has a duration of 13.38 hours, the second record is 0.19 hours, and the third record is 0.05 hours, yet the sum produced by the database is 888 seconds, or 0.24 hours.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with javascript. Maybe replace it with PHP?

Comment: I'm not using javascript for this code, its entirely PHP and mysql

Comment: Maybe the first row have some different username or payperiod values?

Comment: No, the first row has all of the same information. When I select all data from the table for the given username and pay period, it currently shows 3 rows of data matching that query. When I then sum the duration column for those 3 rows, the result of the sum only shows the combined value of the second and third row, but never the first.

Comment: Did you try to run the SQL statement directly in your database, without using PHP?

Comment: From the screenshot I'll postulate that `02/14/2019 02:54:04` is UTC but `Pay Period` is in local time (some tz < -3 UTC) thus considering that record as `02/13/2019`

Comment: All times stored in the database are stored as Unix Timestamps and only displayed on the page in a more user friendly format. All queries and math functions are performed on the data in timestamp format. When I run the queries on the database itself, without PHP I get the same results. There are 3 records found matching the query however the sum function is only summing 2 of the three duration values.

Comment: Please show us the DDL for the table and provide some sample data.

Comment: @pschild, Yes, I ran the same queries on the database itself and got the same results as the PHP code. There are 3 records in the query, the first is 13.38 hours, the second is 0.19 hours and the third is 0.05 hours, yet the sum returned is only 0.24 hours (the sum of only the last 2 rows and not the first). Regardless of the data fed into the database the outcome seems to be the same, its summing all rows but the first row in the query.

Comment: @Dave, I uploaded some screenshots with values for reference. These are the actual values in the query and the sum result. The correct result should be in excess of 13 hours, since the first row is 13.38 hours, but the sum result is only the sum of the second and third row (0.24 hours).

Comment: The database is showing the 3 values as 49774, 541, and 339 but the sum of those 3 values is returned as 888.

Comment: In your first query you are using `timestamp_in BETWEEN x AND y`, in the SUM query you are using `payperiod='x - y'`. Where is the column `payperiod`? And can you try to use the WHERE clause `timestamp_in BETWEEN x AND y` for calculating the sum and see what that's resulting in?

Comment: yes, what is the type and the values for the payperiod field?

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution. I changed the query from:

```
$xxy = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(duration) AS totalsum FROM timesheet WHERE username='$qname' AND payperiod='02/14/2019 - 02/21/2019'");

$xxy = mysqli_query($mysqli,"SELECT SUM(duration) AS totalsum FROM timesheet WHERE username='$qname' AND status='CLOCKED OUT' AND (timestamp_in BETWEEN '$start_date' AND '$end_date')");
```

Changing the queries resolved the problem, but I did not figure out the cause of the issue. Regardless of how I wrote the queries, the results returned were the same but the sum was wrong with the first query and correct with the second.

Thanks everyone for your input and helping me to resolve this.